# Frequent Sequence stats

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence, reshape

I have a purchase transaction data set. Below is a dummy data set for illustration. I am trying to figure out how reshape/dcast to get most frequent sequences of purchase.

```
require(data.table)

MainID=c('A1','A1','A2','C1','C1','C1','D2','D2','D2','A1','D2')
Purchase=c('A','B','C','A','A','D','E','B','C','E','E')
Date=c('1/1/2014','5/23/2015','6/12/2015','3/3/2013','5/5/2014','7/21/2014','1/3/2016','4/5/2016','7/7/2016','6/27/2016')

df=data.table(MainID,Purchase,Date)
head(df)

   MainID Purchase      Date
1:     A1        A  1/1/2014
2:     A1        B 5/23/2015
3:     A2        C 6/12/2015
4:     C1        A  3/3/2013
5:     C1        A  5/5/2014
6:     C1        D 7/21/2014
```

Now here i seek multiple combinations of sequence in pairs of 2 for a start . Like for dataset above following are set of unique sequence pairs : ( A leads to B , B leads to C , A leads to D , E leads to B , and last C leads to E )
Note here i dont take of A to A - i am looking at sequence of distinct products not same products. Hence in output i would like to ignore all those similar product sequences.

Output required :

```
Pair                  Occurrence         No of customers        % confidence 
A leads to B             1                    3                    1/3
B leads to C             2                    3                    2/3
A leads to D             1                    3                    1/3
E leads to B             1                    3                    1/3
C leads to E             2                    3                    2/3
```

I am aware of sequencing algorithms but i am looking at some basic descriptive analysis here.

Comment: I don't understand how to get to your required output from your data. Is the sequence for the same purchase ? Do you want to combine your purchase with the next line ? Is the first letter of MainID important ?

Comment: Main ID is just unique identifier and A,B,C,D,E are dummy products. The order of the data can be mixed and not necessarily in next line. So overall i want to aggregate purchases at an ID level , order them as per date , and then see what sequences of purchase he shows . For example A1 customer above shows ( A to B , B to C , and then C to E as he again purchases in the end) like i this i want to calculate all possible sequences for each customer and see which one occurs the most , overall at an aggregated level.

Comment: Is A2 as MainID on the 3rd element a typo ? A date is missing also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, this may work. Note that I changed A2 to A1 from your data, and that I added a date so as to have a length 11 vector for Date. I also created a tibble directly instead of using data.table.

```
MainID=c('A1','A1','A1','C1','C1','C1','D2','D2','D2','A1','D2')
Purchase=c('A','B','C','A','A','D','E','B','C','E','E')
Date=c('1/1/2014','5/23/2015','6/12/2015','3/3/2013','5/5/2014','7/21/2014','1/3/2016','4/5/2016','7/7/2016','6/27/2016', '8/8/2016')
df=data_frame(MainID,Purchase,Date)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(MainID) %>%
  arrange(MainID, Date) %>%
  mutate(Next = lead(Purchase, 1),
         Pair = paste(Purchase, "leads to", Next)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Next), Purchase != Next) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Pair) %>%
  summarise(Occurence = n()) %>%
  mutate(N_consumers = length(unique(MainID)),
         Percent_confidence = paste0(Occurence, "/", N_consumers))

df2
# A tibble: 5 <U+00D7> 4
          Pair Occurence N_consumers Percent_confidence
         <chr>     <int>       <int>              <chr>
1 A leads to B         1           3                1/3
2 A leads to D         1           3                1/3
3 B leads to C         2           3                2/3
4 C leads to E         2           3                2/3
5 E leads to B         1           3                1/3
```